# Ssh Key Generation Algorithm

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

Ssh provides more than 1 algorithm for encryption of session data. Is the performance of each different ? If so,  which is the best one?

Comment: SSH has several symmetric ciphers for data encryption, and several publickey authentication algorithms which do not encrypt anything. The keys you generate with `ssh-keygen` are only for the latter; if you mean those, ECDSA and Ed25519 are usually fastest when they work but aren't available with older systems, RSA is slow for sign but fast for verify which roughly balance out, and DSA is medium for both. But unless you are doing hundreds of connections (logins) per second, you probably won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] algorithm for encryption of session data.

You can find out what ciphers your client and server supports using  (if you have quite recent version):

```
ssh -Q cipher
sshd -T | grep ciphers
```

There is a lot of ancient ciphers, that are fast, but no longer considered secure (`3des-cbc`, `blowfish-cbc`, `arcfour`).

The reasonable one is `aes*-*` (different modes and key sizes from 128 to 256), which is usually implemented as special instruction in processor and makes it really fast.

Current default is `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`, which is combination of cipher and MAC ([Message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)) and does also good job.

In this case, key generation is completely unrelated, because it is used only for establishing session, host and client verification/authentication, but not for encryption of session data.

Comment: Isn't the default symmetric algorithm 3des ?(Specified in ssh_config) . Do you mean the session data is not encrypted by default?

Comment: Maybe in some old versions. You can find current default in manual page for `ssh_config` and `sshd_config`. No. I mean that session data is encrypted by keys established during key-exchange phase and not using the keys generated using `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: Will the performace vary with the employed algorithm for large data sizes?

Comment: Generally yes. But it depends on many factors that you need to cover into your measurements. On network throughput, latency, on hardware on both client and server side. If you aim for the best performance, you would do the best if you would just try in your environment.

Comment: When i tried to intercepting packets of an ssh connection using wireshark, packets were  unencrypted. Do i have to set the tunnel option in ssh_config to 'yes' ?

Comment: Which packets? Session packets with your data? Passowrds? No, the tunnel option is for different use cases, as you can read in manual.